# How Midpoint Estimation Formula Be Found?

Tags: calculus, approximation

How do we get the midpoint estimation formula?
I mean this formula $En = \frac{(b-a)^3}{24n^2}\max(f^"(c))\ and\ a \le c \le b$.
I have known how the left / right estimation formulas get found. It uses the worst case of graph where the derivatives of all points are maximum then we can just look for the estimation.
But I don't understand the rest especially I need the midpoint one. What even $f^"(x) $ has to do with the formula? it looks weird since it means we can set the first derivative whatever number we want.

[Purcell 9th](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkCvz.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

Comment: Please learn how to ask questions properly : the word "error"or more exactly "error bounding" is missing in your title and in your text.

Comment: ahh.. I see. I thought my question was fine. Yet when I start reading other's question, they really try hard to explain it. my bad.. thankss anyway